# How to adjust the range of the regression line in SAS proc sgplot

Tags: sas, sgplot

The SAS code for the data and plot is below. The regression line will be determined by the 10 data point I have, but I want to control the start and the end of the regression line. For example, I want to keep my current plot, the only change is that I want the regression line begin at day=3 and end at day=8. Now the regression line begin at day=1 and end at day=10. How can I do it?

```
data my_data;
    input day sales;
    datalines;
1 7
2 12
3 15
4 14
5 13
6 11
7 10
8 16
9 18
10 24
;
run;

proc sgplot data=my_data;
    reg x=day y=sales;
     xaxis min=0 max = 12 values=(0 to 12 by 1);
     yaxis min=0 max = 25 values=(0 to 25 by 1);
run;
```

Comment: I mean the formula for the regression line doesn't change at all, it was determined by the 10 data point I have. Just change the start and the end of the regression line on the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to capture the computed regression line coefficients from `Proc REG` output and add the endpoints of your desired line segment as rows to the data to be plotted with a `SERIES` statement.

Since you are going to essentially hide the `SGPLOT REG` line you can plot the data points with just `SCATTER`

Example:

The `REG` statement is used for instructive purposes and to show the computed line segment from `Proc REG` does align with the line computed for `REG` statement.  The `SERIES` line was thickened for instructive purposes.

```
data have;
    input day sales;
    datalines;
1 7
2 12
3 15
4 14
5 13
6 11
7 10
8 16
9 18
10 24
;
run;

ods html file='reg.html';

ods exclude all;
ods output ParameterEstimates=PE;
proc reg data=have;
   model sales = day;
run;
ods exclude none;
proc transpose data=PE prefix=coeff_ out=coeff(keep=coeff_:);
  var estimate;
  id variable;
run;

data line;
  set coeff;
  day = 3; sales_y = coeff_intercept + coeff_day * day; output;
  day = 8; sales_y = coeff_intercept + coeff_day * day; output;
  keep day sales_y;
  label sales_y = 'sales';
run;

data plotdata;
  set have line;
run;


proc sgplot data=plotdata noautolegend;
  * scatter x=day y=sales;

    reg x=day y=sales;

    series x=day y=sales_y / lineattrs=(thickness=12);

    xaxis min=0 max=12 values=(0 to 12 by 2)  minor minorcount=1;
    yaxis min=0 max=25 values=(0 to 25 by 5)  minor minorcount=4;

run;
ods html close;
```

[image]